# After dynamic array creation tried to push values into array dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 3 arrays as follows:

Which I have created dynamically

```
var count =3;
for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        eval('var array' + j + '=[]');
    }

array0[] , array1[], array2[]
```

And having another array:

```
var arraycomp = [1,2,3];
```

And I have another array :

```
var valarray = [1,2,3,2,1,3,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

What I do is as follows:

```
for(var k=0;k<arraycomp.length;k++){
 for(var i=0;i<valarray.length;i++){
   if(valarray[i]==arraycomp[k]){
     var arrayname = "array"+k;
     arrayname.push(valarray[i]);
   }
 }
}
```

What I need is:

```
 array0[] having 1's
 array2[] having 2's       
 array3[] having 3's
```

But it is not working:

I am getting error in:

```
var arrayname = "array"+k;
arrayname.push(valarray[i]);
```

Error is:

> Can not push to arrayname

I tried an alternative as:

```
var arrayname = "array"+k;
var len = arrayname .length;
arrayname [len ] = valarray[i];
```

How can I make this consider as array: `var arrayname = "array"+k;` it is taking as variable.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using `eval()` to create your arrays? The pattern you're using is not great and could be far better served with an object. Also, `arrayname` is a string which doesn't have a `push()` method, hence the error. If you can explain a little more about why you need to do this we can offer some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code is not going to work.

```
if(valarray[i]==arraycomp[k]){
    var arrayname = "array"+k;
    arrayname.push(valarray[i]);
}
```

("array"+k) is still going to be a string like "array0" or "array1". It's not an array so it's not possible to use it as an array. You can try to use eval() to get the array instance but as @Rory pointed out you should not use eval(). It's one of the evils of the Javascript and has very specific use cases, creating Arrays is not one of them.

You can try creating a 2 dimensional array for your program, as shown below

```
var count =3;
var my2dArr = [];
var arraycomp = [1,2,3];
var valarray = [1,2,3,2,1,3,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    my2dArr.push([]);
}
for(var k=0;k<arraycomp.length;k++){
    for(var i=0;i<valarray.length;i++){
        if(valarray[i]==arraycomp[k]){
            my2dArr[k].push(valarray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

In Javascript a 2d array is just an array of arrays so all the sub arrays can have arbitrary length.

Comment: thanks for alternate solution. it solved my problem!!

Answer (score 2):

Here you try to push the value to the string.

```
var arrayname = "array"+k;
arrayname.push(valarray[i]);
```

As these two are equivalent in JS:

```
var x = 1;
this.x = 1;
```

and these two are equivalent as well:

```
obj[prop]
obj.prop
```

You may access a variable using dynamically generated string name this way:

```
var arrayname = "array"+k;
this[arrayname].push(valarray[i]);
```

You may also want to declare it in the same way:

```
var count =3;
for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    //eval('var array' + j + '=[]');
    this['array' + j] = [];
}
```

However, in general, all these manipulations with both `eval` and `this[]` are wrong. You can define an array of arrays, an object with arrays or whatever else - anything will be better than creating variables in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var arrayname = "array"+k;
arrayname.push(valarray[i]);
```

Use:

```
var arrayname = "array"+k;
var window[arrayname].push(valarray[i]);
```

That is because `arrayname` is a string ("array0", "array1" etc.)

Accessing `arrayname` on the window object will work only if `eval` is called within the global scope (i.e. not from a function).

Replace `eval('var array' + j + '=[]');` with `eval('window.array' + j + '=[]');` as workaround.

Or better yet, use [escodegen](https://github.com/estools/escodegen), [estemplate](https://github.com/estools/estemplate) or some other AST-based tool for meta programming if dynamic code is *really* what you need.